# Evernote javascript bookmark importer

Tags: javascript, xml, evernote

Evernote user 'iwqnna' has created a great javascript tool for importing html bookmarks into Evernote: http://jsfiddle.net/kT4nj/ (description [here](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/27609-tool-import-chrome-netscape-bookmarks-to-evernote/page__gopid__159970#entry159970)). Unfortunately it doesn't import the additional notes that can be contained in Google Bookmarks. Do you know how I could modify the javascript import tool to maintain this additional info as well?

In the html file I am importing from (exported from Google Bookmarks) the additional note data comes after the `<DD>` tag.

e.g.

```
<H3 ADD_DATE="1344874450147601">Tag name here</H3>
<DL><p>
<DT><A HREF="url 1 here" ADD_DATE="date here">Bookmark 1 name here</A><DD>More detailed note about bookmark 1 here
<DT><A HREF="url 2 here" ADD_DATE="date here">Bookmark 2 name here</A><DD>More detailed note about bookmark 2 here
</DL>
```

Additionally, although the existing tool successfully imports notes into Evernote desktop, there seem to be some issues with syncing notes imported via this script. The activity log says:

e.g.

> 21:13:41 [576] 86% Skipping note "note name here" flagged as
> unsyncable (0x4) local flags (ENML_VALIDATION)

Any ideas? This is the closest I've come to a satisfactory import solution when running Windows, and I'd really appreciate some help clearing the last hurdle. Many thanks.